# MySQL Updating wrong column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am having a strange problem in my mysql. The table contains around 20 million rows.
The structure of the table is:

```
    create table session_table (id int, start_datetime
    datetime,start_date_int int, start_time_int, end_datetime datetime, 
    end_date_int int, end_datetime_int int)
```

The integer version of the date, e,g.,  start_date_int and end_date_int columns are for storing the date as an integer using to_days() function. MySQL TO_DAYS() returns number of days between a given date and year 0. Similarly start_time_int and end_time_int columns store the unix_timestamp of the datetime value.

Now see the following update statement:

```
    update session_table
    SET
      start_date_int=to_days(start_datetime),
      start_datetime_int=UNIX_TIMESTAMP((start_datetime),
      end_date_int=to_days(end_datetime),
      end_datetime_int=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_datetime)
    where start_datetime >= '2016-07-01 00:00:00'
```

The update statment worked fine before. However today it seems it is only updating the rows for  '2016-10-03' (my observation is based on count) and strangely it is updating the start_datetime column with the datetime i am issuing the query, although I have not put this column in the update statement!

Is there any possibility that the mysql server got corrupted? It is a very data intensive system where we have many tables with lot of data, e.g, 20-30 million rows with lot of insert, update process.

Also is there any possiblity that data might get deleted for few days automatically sometime for mysql scalability?
Please give your opinion/suggestion on this.

Comment: It is much more likely that you have made a mistake in interpreting what has happened.  It is hard to imagine how MySQL could be so surgically corrupted, as to allow the operations to happen (without error) but to update the wrong columns.  I did once have a similar problem with SQL Server, which was the result of a column being inserted into the table, but the code not being re-compiled.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am writing directly the update statement using navicat for mysql tool. I re-cehcked the update statement several times and also showed it to two other developer. But still it is updating the start_datetime and end_datetiem columns :(

Answer (score 1):

I think that some of your columns are `auto-computed`, you can check if there is a `trigger` on this table maybe after update and it may fill the `start_datetime/end_datetime` according to the updated values of `start_datetime_int/end_datetime_int`.
I hope this helps...

Comment: I have a trigger for insert, but not for update. The insert trigger fills start_datetime_int value based on the new start_datetime value when a new row is inserted. Today we are going to restart the server. Let's see whether it helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

After doing further investigation I found that in the table design of navicat for mysql, someone checked in a check box called "on update current_timestamp" option for the start_datetime and end_datetime columns and it was causing this problem. My bad. Thanks for your feedback.

The Navicat for mysql has a this option enabled by default. So, one should be always careful while creating a table using Navicat when the table has datetime column.

Comment: This is an example of why you should post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE session_table` when you ask a question, instead of what you *think* the table definition should be.